# The sample for kbmMW CG edition doesn't work (Delphi DX10)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I installed kbmMW CG for Delphi DX10.

It was installed successful, but when I opened sample demo from \SQL\VCL\ folder I found the same errors:

```
 - "Class TkbmFMXMemo not found ....."   
 - "Class TkbmFMXDBGrid not found   ....."     
 - ......
```

How to correct errors?

```
CocoAncestor.dcu
history.txt
installation.txt
kbmList.dcu
kbmMemBinaryStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMemCSVStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMemDesD10CG.bpl
kbmMemDesD10CG.dcp
kbmMemResEng.dcu
kbmMemRunD10CG.bpl
kbmMemRunD10CG.dcp
kbmMemSQL.dcu
kbmMemTable.dcu
kbmMemtableDoc.url
kbmMemTypes.dcu
kbmMove.dcu
kbmMW.inc
kbmMW.url
kbmMW.wsdl
kbmMWBinaryStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMWClient.dcu
kbmMWClientDataset.dcu
kbmMWConfig.inc
kbmMWConfig.sam
kbmMWConnectionString.dcu
kbmMWCustomConnectionPool.dcu
kbmMWCustomDataset.dcu
kbmMWCustomMemoryStreamFormatter.dcu
kbmMWCustomQueryService.dcu
kbmMWCustomQueryService.dfm
kbmMWCustomSQLMetaData.dcu
kbmMWCustomTransport.dcu
kbmmwd.chm
kbmMWDateTime.dcu
kbmMWDBX.dcu
kbmMWDebug.dcu
kbmMWDebugMapFile.dcu
kbmMWDebugStackTrace.dcu
kbmMWDebugTdsFile.dcu
kbmMWDesD10CG.bpl
kbmMWDesD10CG.dcp
kbmMWDesD10CG.dpk
kbmMWDesD10CG.dproj
kbmMWExceptions.dcu
kbmMWFireDAC.dcu
kbmMWGlobal.dcu
kbmMWHTTPStdTransStream.dcu
kbmMWHTTPUtils.dcu
kbmMWIBX5.dcu
kbmMWInterbaseMetaData.dcu
kbmMWInventoryClient.dcu
kbmMWInventoryService.dcu
kbmMWInventoryService.dfm
kbmMWISAPIClientTransport.dcu
kbmMWISAPIServerTransport.dcu
kbmMWISAPITransport.dcu
kbmMWJSON.dcu
kbmMWJSONStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMWLocalStats.dcu
kbmMWLocalTransport.dcu
kbmMWLog.dcu
kbmMWLZ.dcu
kbmMWLZHCompression.dcu
kbmMWMD.dcu
kbmMWMime.dcu
kbmMWMSSQLMetaData.dcu
kbmMWMT.dcu
kbmMWNullable.dcu
kbmMWObject.dcu
kbmMWObjectUtils.dcu
kbmMWOracleMetaData.dcu
kbmMWPreConfig.inc
kbmMWProxyService.dcu
kbmMWProxyService.dfm
kbmMWQueryService.dcu
kbmMWQueryService.dfm
kbmMWQueryServiceSetup.dcu
kbmMWQueryServiceSetup.dfm
kbmMWResolvers.dcu
kbmMWRunD10CG.bpl
kbmMWRunD10CG.dcp
kbmMWRunD10CG.dpk
kbmMWRunD10CG.dproj
kbmMWSecurity.dcu
kbmMWSequence.dcu
kbmMWServer.dcu
kbmMWServer.dfm
kbmMWServiceSetup.dcu
kbmMWServiceUtils.dcu
kbmMWServiceWizard.dcu
kbmMWSOAPTransStream.dcu
kbmMWSQLITE.dcu
kbmMWSQLUtils.dcu
kbmMWStats.dcu
kbmMWStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMWSubjectUtils.dcu
kbmMWTCPIPIndyClientTransport.dcu
kbmMWTCPIPIndyServerTransport.dcu
kbmMWTCPIPIndyTransport.dcu
kbmMWXML.dcu
kbmMWXMLDomStreamFormatter.dcu
kbmMWXMLStreamFormat.dcu
kbmMWXMLTransStream.dcu
kbmSQLDBAPI.dcu
kbmSQLElements.dcu
kbmSQLFuncAPI.dcu
kbmSQLMemTableAPI.dcu
kbmSQLParser.dcu
kbmSQLStdFunc.dcu
kbmString.dcu
license.txt
```

This is kbmMW Folder.
We have only 4 bpl-files.

Comment: You need to install the design time packages

Comment: Hi David, what that mean.

Comment: Er, do you know how components are installed in Delphi?

Comment: I included information about all files. We have only 4 bpl-files. I installed bpl files.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this at all. Please read the installation documentation carefully again. If that doesn't work, please contact the vendor of this component for support.

Comment: Also please note that I re-tagged the question. You are not using Delphi XE.  That is a release from around 5 years ago. You are using Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: I published this question because I'm looking for people who have experience with this library, I contacted with the vendor, but still got no answer. And DX10 is Delphi DX 10 Seatle.

Comment: Kim Madsen is helpful I believe. Does he really not offer support. Your question was tagged incorrectly. You are not using XE as you tagged it. I'm trying to help you learn. On the face of it it seems you are not an expert and do need help.

Comment: You solve the errors by doing exactly what David told you, which is to install the design time packages. Component->Install Package from the IDE's main menu.

Comment: I checked packages in Component->Install Package. It has two bpls kbmmw and kbmMemTable. I past information about all lib files (see main post). This folder has only 4 bpls files. they are already installed. What the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Redownload latest kbmMW CodeGear Edition for D10 Seattle. It will contain updated demos, and a couple of missing files from the original installation, and will be based on the latest kbmMW/kbmMemTable version.